# Как передать данные из одной формы в другую?

Tags: javascript, php, html, form

**Допустим у нас на странице два товара с кнопкой купить, под каждым товаром есть форма со скрытыми полями описанием (артикул, цена) и кнопкой купить.**

И в конце на этой же странице есть ещё одна **"главная"** форма.

**Подскажите пожалуйста - Как при нажатии submit в одной из таких форм, передать value этих полей в главную форму?**

Чтоб было понятнее, вот грубый пример этих форм:

*Товар1(первая форма)*

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" id="articul" name="articul" value="001">
<input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="100руб">
<div id="sendValues">Отправить</div>
```

*Товар2 (Вторая форма)*

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" id="articul" name="articul" value="002">
<input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="250руб">
<div id="sendValues">Отправить</div>
```

*Оформление заказа (Главная форма отправляющая данные дальше для обработки)*

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="Name" name="Имя"  value="">
<input type="text" id="Phone" name="Телефон" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="realarticul" name="articul" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="realprice" name="price" value="">
```

**Буду благодарен за помощь!**

Сам делал с помощью jQuery:

```
$('.sendValues').click(function(){
$('#realarticul').val( $('#articul').val() );
$('#realaprice').val( $('#price').val() );
```

});

Но тут не важно какую кнопку нажмешь, данные подставляются из первой формы!

Comment: зачем вы цену в форму выводите?

Comment: Вы корзину какую-то делаете? тогда при клике Отправить вам в сессию надо сохранить идентификаторы и число товаров. а уже на странице оформления из сессии взять и посчитать. Цену берете всегда из базы. А то вам кто-нить так ее руками в редакторе и подправит.

Comment: Спасибо, но я в программировании не силён. Про сессию ничего не знаю. Ну тут не то чтобы корзина, а одностраничник и всего 3 товара. Думал можно как то простым кодом обойтись -> ткнул на товар, скролл вниз на форму "имя" и "телефон" и кнопка "заказать" вот и вся корзина!